# Small confusing concerning union of path connected spaces

Tags: general-topology

This is exercise 1.20 in Joseph J. Rotman „An Introduction to Algebraic Topology“, which states that for two path connected subspaces $A,B\subset X$ with $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$ path connected also $A\cup B$ is path connected. But is path-connectedness of the intersection really needed? For me it seems to be obvious that „non-empty“ should suffice, but also I assume it is written down there for a reason...    I would be glad if somebody would clarify this for me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the intersection doesn't have to be path connected. Let $x,y\in A\cup B$. If both points are in $A$ or both in $B$ then just use the fact that $A,B$ are path connected. So the only interesting case is when $x\in A, y\in B$. By assumption there is some point $z\in A\cap B$. Now take a path from $x$ to $z$ which is contained in $A$, then take a path from $z$ to $y$ which is contained in $B$. Combining them together we get a path from $x$ to $y$ which is contained in $A\cup B$. So we never used the path connectedness of $A\cap B$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I thought. But the extra assumption confused me so much that I needed some sort of affirmation...